# MySQL several sorting conditions: WHERE and LIMIT in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a database and i want to sort results like this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM pictures  LIMIT 0,10 "; 

    $result = mysql_query($query1);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))        
            echo $row['picture_rating'];
```

and

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM pictures  WHERE  column_name = 'column_text' "; 

    $result = mysql_query($query1);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))        
            echo $row['picture_rating'];
```

Both of the codes above are working properly, but when i want to use both condition at one time like this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM pictures  LIMIT 0,10 WHERE  column_name = 'column_text' ";
```

it doesnt work. Any ideas how to make it work? Thanx!

SOLVED:
Information that LIMIT should be after WHERE was exactly what i needed. Thanx to all.

Comment: WHERE should be before LIMIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE column_name = 'column_text' LIMIT 0,10";
```

Comment: Thanx, information that LIMIT should be after WHERE was exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 4):

the SQL syntax for SELECT defines that LIMIT should be after WHERE

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [MySQL documentation on `SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), you will see, that the `WHERE` clause has to come *before* the `LIMIT` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `pictures`
WHERE  `column_name` = 'column_text'
LIMIT 0,10
```